# declaring a class with struct keyword and vice versa

Tags: c++, class, struct, declaration

But of course we shouldn't even think of doing such things, I know, but still this is quite interesting:

```
class A; //declaration
struct A {...}; //definition

struct B; //declaration
class B {...}; //definition
```

When I think about it, I don't see any problems if such a thing were really allowed(because struct and class are essentially the same thing). But is it (standard-wise)?

MSVC accepts and compiles it, with a warning.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is allowed according to the standard, but as some compilers warn about it, it is not very useful.

I believe the warning is/was caused by MSVC using a different name mangling for structs and classes, which would make it even less useful...

---

On request from @Armen:

7.1.5.3 Elaborated type specifiers, p3

> ... in any *elaborated-type-specifier*, the `enum` keyword shall be used to refer to an enumeration (7.2), the `union` *class-key* shall be used to refer to a union (clause 9), and either the `class` or `struct` *class-key* shall be used to refer to a class (clause 9), declared using the `class` or `struct` *class-key*.

Comment: Any quotes from the standard that allow it?

Comment: @Armen - Added a quote, well hidden in chapter 7. :-)

Answer (score 5):

As per ***C++03 Standard 9.1 - 2***

*"A class definition introduces the class name into the scope where it is defined and hides any class, object, function, or other declaration of that name in an enclosing scope (3.3)."*

So it is valid as per the standard.

Playing around a bit with the example code:

```
#include<iostream>

class A; //declaration 
struct A { int i;}; //definition  
struct B; //declaration 
class B {int j;}; //definition 

int main()
{
    A obj;
    obj.i = 10;
    B obj2;
    obj2.j = 10;
    std::cout<<"sizeof"<<sizeof(struct B);
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the output:

```
prog.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
prog.cpp:6: error: ‘int B::j’ is private
prog.cpp:13: error: within this context
```

The only difference between C++ struct & class is that default access specifier for structure is public while for class it is private.

So, From the above example:
In this case compiler treats `A` as a `structure` &
`B` as a `class`

As you see, the compiler follows the quote from the standard and the type with the definition is what the compiler recognizes, over the declaration type.

Comment: @Als: How does this paragraph imply that what I wrote is allowed? oO

Comment: @Armen Tsirunyan: If the definition hides any declaration of that name in an enclosing scope, then should'nt what you wrote be resolved as per the standard quote?

Comment: @Als: I think both `struct A` and `class A {...}` refer to the same entity, no name hiding... Or am I missing something?

Comment: @Armen Tsirunyan: I am evaluating the quote to, Presence of definition `struct A {...};` hides the declaration `class A;`.

Comment: @Als: But hiding the name isn't enough, is it? The compiler must understsand that the definition of the class refers to the previous declaration... I am wrong?

Comment: @Armen Tsirunyan: Updated the answer.

Comment: There is no hiding going on here... fully define both `class A` and `struct A` in the above code, and see what happens.

Comment: @Als: That's not the "only" difference. Don't forget about inheritance.